# Ecommerce tracking tag not reporting products

Tags: google-analytics

Here is my code:

```
ga('require', 'ecommerce');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id' : '41',
  'affiliation': 'My Store',
  'revenue' : '28.18',
  'shipping' : '6.99',
  'tax': '1.20' 
});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
   'id' : '41', 
   'name' : 'EXAMPLE ITEM', 
   'sku' : 'XXXXX23',
   'category' : 'Store Main', 
   'price' : '19.99', 
   'quantity' :'1'
}); 
ga('ecommerce:send');
```

I have been able to  get the transaction recording to Google Analytics, however the products/items are not recording at all. In the Google Analytics debugger I can see that the data is being sent, but it is not in the reports. It's been more than 48 hours (more like 2 weeks) and I still don't see it. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you enable ecommerce in the View settings?

Comment: I assume you are, but are you including the GA base code containing your property id above the code that you posted?

Comment: What methodology are you using? This seems to be very different to what is recommended: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#transaction

Comment: I did enable ecommerce in the View settings, I am currently able to record transactions just not items/products. the property id is set in the header which is included in all of our pages. I am not using enhanced ecommerce in this instance, is that a requirement?